# Trying to run a for loop using webdriver-io and mocha gives me "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'waitForDisplayed')"

Tags: mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to loop through a JSON  file which of users and test logging in and out as each user, but when trying to use a for loop I get the following error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'waitForDisplayed') is there anyway to run for loop using webdriver-io and mocha?

```
//this is the "UserList"
{
    "Operator":{
        "username" : "user.1",
        "password" : "password.1"
    },
   "Driver":{
        "username": "user.2",
        "password" : "password.2"
   }
    
}
```

```
/**
 *
 * @format
 */
/* eslint-disable wdio/await-expect */

import "colors";
const SettingsScreen = require("../screens/settings.screen");
const LoginScreen = require("../screens/login.screen");
const loggedInScreen = require("../screens/loggedIn.screen");
const testUsers = require("./UserList");
const utils = require("../helpers/utils");

let timeout = 10000;
let simulator = false;

describe("Login with multiple roles", () => {
  before(() => {
    require("expect-webdriverio").setOptions({ wait: 5000 });
  });

  it("Should allow log in with multiple roles", async () => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(testUsers)) {
      await multipleUserLogin(key, value.username, value.password);
    }
  });
});

async function multipleUserLogin(key, username, password) {
  const loginButton = await LoginScreen.loginButton;
  await loginButton.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: timeout });
  await loginButton.click();

  const userNameField = await LoginScreen.usernameField;
  await userNameField.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: timeout });
  await userNameField.click();
  await userNameField.setValue(username);
  await expect(userNameField).toHaveText(username);
}
```